Changing pulse frequency on Qiskit Pulse
I'm just starting to explore the Qiskit Pulse module. In order to conserve my allocated time on the IBM platform, I’m trying to work with a simulator first (FakeBackend). However, when I create a schedule and attempt to run it on a FakeBackend, I encounter an error stating that schedules cannot be executed on either 'V1 fake backends' or 'V2 backends.'
While searching for a solution in the documentation, I came across the DynamicsBackend class in the qiskit_dynamics package, which seems to support pulse execution. With it, I finally can run my scheduled circuits.
However, I'm having difficulty changing the qubit frequency. The instruction pulse.set_frequency(frequency, drive_chan) does not raise an exception but seems to have no effect on the results. Here, frequency refers to the desired frequency (a float value) for the pulse, and drive_chan is the DriveChannel to which this change should be applied.
To test this, I set the pulse amplitude to 0 (or actually very close to it just in case) and selected a non-zero pulse frequency. According to the Hamiltonian of the transmon qubit, this pulse should be equivalent to a Z-rotation. With this idea on mid, I performed the following experiment: If I set the pulse frequency to the natural qubit frequency, with the pulse amplitude at zero, the operation should be equivalent to an identity gate, so my qubit should remain ideally at its original state. However, if I change the frequency, I should start observing a Z-rotation. My experiment, therefore, involves varying the pulse frequency over a range centered around the natural qubit frequency. I sandwich this pulse with Hadamard gates to observe correctly the application of the Z-rotation. Finally, I estimate the probability of measuring $|0\rangle$ at the end of the circuit. In other words, I run the following code:
from qiskit import pulse, QuantumCircuit, transpile, schedule
from qiskit.circuit import Parameter
from qiskit_dynamics import DynamicsBackend
from qiskit_ibm_runtime.fake_provider import FakeManila
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from warnings import filterwarnings
filterwarnings('ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)

q = 0   # index qubit to use

# Create the DynamicsBackend from FakeManila
fm_backend = FakeManila()
backend = DynamicsBackend.from_backend(fm_backend)
dt = fm_backend._configuration.dt


# Create a parametric schedule -> amp = 0 and freq = parameter
freq_param = Parameter('pulse frequency')

with pulse.build(backend=backend, name='amp0freqGate') as freq_sched:
    drive_chan = pulse.drive_channel(q)
    pulse.set_frequency(freq_param, drive_chan)
    # pulse.SetFrequency(freq, drive_chan)   # same effect as set_frequency
    pulse.play(pulse.Gaussian(duration=pulse.seconds_to_samples(8*dt) ,    # for instance
                              sigma=pulse.seconds_to_samples(dt) ,     # for instance
                              amp=1e-8),   # not 0, but close to it
               drive_chan)

# Convert Block Schedule to Schedule (is there a better way?)
freq_sched_ = pulse.Schedule()
freq_sched_.initialize_from(freq_sched)

# get the pulse corresponding to a h gate
qc_h = QuantumCircuit(1)
qc_h.h(q)
qc_h = transpile(qc_h, fm_backend)
h_pulse = schedule(qc_h, fm_backend)

# gate the pulse for a measurement
qc_measure = QuantumCircuit(1, 1)
qc_measure.measure(q, q)
qc_measure = transpile(qc_measure, fm_backend)
meas_pulse = schedule(qc_measure, fm_backend)

# Create the circuit merging the schedules
sched = h_pulse.insert(h_pulse.stop_time, freq_sched_)
sched = sched.insert(h_pulse.stop_time + sched.stop_time, h_pulse)
sched = sched.insert(2 * h_pulse.stop_time + sched.stop_time,meas_pulse)

# Assign parameters to run
q_freq = fm_backend._configuration.hamiltonian["vars"]['wq0']   # natural qubit frequency
span = 0.3
freq_range = np.linspace((1 - span) * q_freq, (1 + span) * q_freq, 7)
scheds = [sched.assign_parameters({freq_param: f}, inplace=False) for f in freq_range]


# Run experiments
probs_0 = []
for sched in scheds:
    counts = backend.run(sched).result().get_counts()
    prob = counts.get('0', 0) / sum(list(counts.values()))
    probs_0.append(prob)


# Plot results
plt.plot(freq_range, probs_0)
plt.xlabel('Frequency (GHz)')
plt.ylabel('Probability of |0>')
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1))
plt.plot(q_freq * np.ones(100), np.linspace(0, 1, 100), ':k')
plt.show()


Which produces the following figure:

Therefore, there are two possibilities: my theoritical analysis is wrong and the results are correct (then it is my fault, not qiskit) or changing the frequency of the pulse is not possible in a simulator. I friend of mine told me once that he had troubles with pulse simulators exactly because of this, but I would like to know if there is another possible way to simulate pulse executions and ensure that the problem is not on my side.
These are the versions of qiskit that I am using:
qiskit version: 1.1.1
qiskit_ibm_runtime version: 0.25.0
qiskit_dynamics version: 0.5.1

Thanks in advance!
